# Disable Flask-SocketIO logging to terminal

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a Flask-SocketIO server running on a mac (Python 2.7.10 Flask 0.10.1) with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'

# app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,port=8000,host='0.0.0.0')
```

It runs fine on mac, but when I run it on a raspberry pi (raspbian, Python 2.7.9, Flask 0.10.1) the same code logs to terminal. As soon as I start it and a client connects I get this in terminal:

```
reading
('send', u'3probe')
reading
('send', u'3')
reading
('send', u'3')
...
```

If I try to send anything using `emit` it gets echoed to the terminal too.

Any ideas how to turn this off? Or where it's coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem that existed in release 0.8.6 of package python-engineio. It has been fixed in version 0.8.7.